# Prove that $\bigcup_{n \in \Bbb{N}} [1/n,1] = (0,1]$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove

$$\bigcup _ { n \in \mathbb { N } } \left[ \frac { 1 } { n } , 1 \right] = ( 0,1 ]$$

---

I'm having some trouble starting this proof because I'm not really sure how to get started on this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Think of them both as sets. How do you prove two sets are equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x$ lies in the big union, which allows us to select a positive integer $k$ so that $1/k \leq x \leq 1 $. Since $\frac{1}{k} > 0$ then $x$ better lie on $(0,1]$. On the other hand, if $x \in (0,1]$, then we may use the archimedean property to cook up an interval of the form you want.